# Bought an app, uninstalled it and automatically got a refund - how to disable?

Tags: google-play-store, 6.0-marshmallow, paid-apps

Few hours ago I bought an app on Google Play Store that I don't need at a moment, but it looked handy and was on sale. I have installed it, fiddled with it for a few minutes and then uninstalled it. As soon as it finished uninstalling, I got an email that my order was cancelled and refunded. The app isn't in my library anymore and I can buy it again.

I don't remember it happening previously when I uninstalled apps just after buying, so it looks like this automatic cancellation was introduced recently. (Or perhaps it's configured per app by developer?)

- **Can I opt out of this feature and not get refunds automatically?**
- Is there any official statement from Google that such feature was enabled?

Comment: This is almost certainly a feature of this specific application.  Why not name it so people can actually investigate your problem?

Comment: It was [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm), if that matters.

Comment: You need it for at least 2 hours

Comment: @rrrrrrrrrr I know that refunds are time-limited, that doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an old question but here is what I could find

- [Google Play Refund Policies](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2479637?hl=en) (click on "refund policies" on first line). says

> You may get an automatic refund if you uninstall a paid app **shortly** after first buying it. If you want to reinstall the app, you'll have to buy it again and you will not be eligible for a refund on that purchase.

(Emphasis added)

- That explains why you got a refund and IMO, it has nothing to do with an app being on sale. It's applicable to paid apps.
- Google doesn't define *shortly* (I couldn't find)
- I couldn't find anything that one can *opt out* to prevent this happening, so don't be in a tearing hurry to uninstall paid apps (you have 48 hours to claim a refund - see [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/131442/131553))
- As per [this blog](https://trendblog.net/get-a-refund-on-google-play-apps-and-in-app/), if you purchase but don't download the app, you can circumvent the immediate - uninstall - refund

Comment: [This Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/3jcldr/til_if_you_uninstall_a_newly_purchased_app_from/) hinted that it has been for a long time (even since Android Market, but questionable...), but the time limit for automatic refund was changed from 24 hours -> 15 minutes -> 2 hours.

Comment: @AndrewT - I have a feeling things are mixed up. 1.for  immediate uninstall as in the Q I couldn't find time limit (doesn't mean it doesn't exist :-) 2.Two hours was the standard refund policy, now it is 48 hours and possibly 15 minutes refers to intimating that your refund is accepted [click on refund policy - follow these instructions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2479637?hl=en) 3. As we know with Google, things keep changing so often, so it's possible what the edit claims may have been applicable at some point

Comment: @AndrewT - see, when I wrote this answer, it was 2 hours, now it is 48! https://android.stackexchange.com/a/131442/131553

Comment: @AndrewT in the comment before last please read reddit for edit

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention the Reddit thread was from 2015...