# How many times can an app purchase be refunded on Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps

How many times can one purchase an app and refund and continue to do so?

Wouldn't continuous refunds hurt Google ?

Answer (score 1):

Paid apps/games!/in-app purchases can only be refunded **once**. If you buy the app again, you can't get refund

From Play Store [help](https://support.google.com/googleplay) (see
Refunds & returns → Learn about refunds on Google Play →Google Play refund policies)

> Note: You can only return an app or game for a refund **once**. If you buy it again you will not be able to get a refund. If a refund is issued you will lose access to the item.

(Emphasis added)

Related: [If a paid app stops working, can I get my money back?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/131438/131553)